# Multiple records getting created in mysql during high load

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am working in a spring data jpa application. As we know by applying spring @Transactional annotation it obey the ACID properties. However I am having an issue. Following is my explanation.

In my current application the business rule for a given post an user is allowed to answer only one answer, if he wants to modify his answer he can edit an answer but can't create another answer for the same post. So for creation and modifying an answer I have two methods. 1. save method and 2. edit method

My question is w.r.t saving an answer which sometime doesn't works as expected in production, i.e. it is not satisfying the business rule and it creates two answer for the same user of a same post. But in local environment this problem never occur. Edit method works fine for me both local environment and production environment.

Following is the sample code snippet of save method in my business logic.

```
@Transactional
public void save(Answer answer) {
    Integer postId = answer.getQuestionId();
    Answer answerFromDb = answerRepository.findByPostIdAndCreatedByIdAndIsDeleted(postId, answer.getCreatedById(), false);
    if(null != answerFromDb) {
        throw new InvalidException("You have already answer for the current post");
    }
    answerRepository.save(answer);
}
```

We are using mysql 5.6 and the default isolation level is REPEATABLE-READ on both local and production environment. i.e.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| tx_isolation  | REPEATABLE-READ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: All primary keys are auto increment and there is one instance of mysql server on production, its not a cluster as of now.

Throwing some light on above issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With repeatable read:

T1 transaction reads data from table Answers and returns certain number of rows. And every subsequent read in T1 will have the same rows. If another concurrent transaction(T2) inserts a row on table Answers after T1 have started, it(T1) will not know that there is one new row.

So one of the possible solutions could be to add an unique key on Answers table so it matches `findByPostIdAndCreatedByIdAndIsDeleted` where condition.

```
ALTER TABLE `Answers` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`post_id`, `createdBy_id`, `deleted`);
```

And wrap the save with try:

```
try {
    answerRepository.save(answer);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    // ignore (there is already an answer)
}
```

Comment: Hey @NikolaB, had thought of adding unique constraint on 'postId', 'createdById' and 'isDeleted' which would prevent from creating one more record.But was interested to know why the two record is being created with a isolation level repetable read which is stricter than read_committed. I had vague idea about the way you have explained. Thanks its confirms my understanding.